# RegEx search and replace link

Tags: regex, asp-classic

We have these texts on webpages

**some blah blah blah ##page1234.asp::the text in the link## and then some more blah blah**

the syntax is double hash, then the link, then double colon, then the text to be clicked and then ending the link with double hash again, as in:

```
##[url]::[visible text]##

##[url]::[visible text]::[title]##
```

Where [title] is the mouse-over text for SEO optimization. Not the most fancy solution, but it has worked for years and wont be changed for time.

What I would like is to speed up the detection/replace function to use RegEx instead of "manually" have vbscript/ASP going through all these documents and doing instr and replace.

My problem is to build the pattern with RegEx that will either replace these with real HTML including

```
<a href="[url]" title="[title]">[visible text]</a>
```

or an array I could work with and perform search and replace with afterwards.

So my 1st priority is to understand RegEx match patterns so it will look for

```
"##<text>::<text>##" or "##<text>::<text>::<text>##"
```

and then return either the whole line, or if possible do the actual html insert too. 
My guess is that it is two different RegEx matches one with 2 variables and one with 3..

**UPDATED with code based upon Sam's regexp:**

```
dim oRegEx, sText
Set oRegEx = New RegExp
oRegEx.Pattern = "##(.*?)::(.*?)(?:::(.*?))?##"
oRegEx.Global = true

sText ="foo ##page1234.asp::visible text## bar ##page1234.xml::visible text::title## bar"
sText = oRegEx.replace( sText, "<a href=""$1"" title=""$3"">$2</a>")

response.Write(sText)
```

Had to change the /1 to a $1 to make it work in vbscript environment. But everything else worked instantly.

Thanks community!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find:

```
##(.*?)::(.*?)(?:::(.*?))?##
```

Replace:

```
<a href="$1" title="$3">$2<a>
```

[***Demo***](http://regex101.com/r/qH9rK9/1)

---

First note that I just made this one expression..so if the optional title attribute (3rd capture group) is missing, we will have a null title attribute (`<a href="page.asp" title="">`).

Now lets expand the expression:

```
##       ?# literally match ##
(.*?)    ?# lazily capture 0+ characters
::       ?# literally match ::
(.*?)    ?# lazily capture 0+ characters
(?:      ?# begin optional non-capturing group
  ::     ?# literally match ::
  (.*?)  ?# lazily capture 0+ characters
)?       ?# end optional non-capturing group
##       ?# literally match ##
```

Comment: And what a great site for the demo, think I will benefit from that in the future.

Comment: Glad I could help, I love Regex101 for writing/testing/sharing expressions.